# Parallel Computing with Python on a queued cluster

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

There are [lots](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) of different modules for threading/parallelizing python.  [Dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/) and [pp/ParallelPython](http://www.parallelpython.com/) seem especially popular.  It looks like these are all designed for a single interface (e.g. desktop) which has many cores/processors.  Is there a module which  works on massively parallel architectures which are run by queue systems (specifically: [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/))?

Comment: Can you add a comment to that downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used parallel framework on large compute clusters for scientific/technical applications is [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). The name of the Python package is [MPI4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/), which is part of [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/).

MPI offers a high-level API for creating parallel software using messages for communicating over the network; remote process creation, data scatter/gather, reductions, etc. All implementations are able to take advantage of fast and low-latency networks if present. It is fully integrated with all cluster managers, including [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Via the ParallelPython main page:

"PP is a python module which provides mechanism for **parallel execution of python code on** SMP (systems with multiple processors or cores) and **clusters (computers connected via network)**."